# Showmodal Userform inside a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am having problems showing a Userform with ShowModal deactivated (to be able to use the spreadsheet while the userform runs). I had used this method before, but I think here it doesn't work because the userform is inside a for loop...

I have looked everywhere and I have tried:

```
Userform1.Show vbModeless   
Userform1.Show 0    
Show Modal = False
...
```

The thing is my userform is inside a for loop So for different values, if they are how i want, I open the userform. The code is something like:

```
 for 
     if...  then
        userform.show 0
      end if
 next
```

When I do this it just does all the operations from the for loop, and then at the end it opens the userform (in modeless mode, but too late..). And if I do it in the normal mode, userform.show, it works perfectly (I just cannot use the spreadsheet)

Does anyone know why it is not working? Let me know if you wanna check the whole code, I didn't post it because it's a bit long..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to 'do anything' with your userform while your loop (and code) is still running you need to add `DoEvents function`  in this way:

(this is my testing sub)

```
Sub test_UF()
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To 3000

        'UserForm is show when i=100
        If i = 100 Then
            'show it in ModeLess state to keep loop running
            UserForm1.Show vbModeless

        End If
            'this is important!!
            DoEvents

            'only for test
            Debug.Print i
    Next

End Sub
```

**Edit** According to comment, if I get you right now, you want to do both:

1. keep userform modeless status and
2. stop loop execution until there is any action from user form.

The only workaround I can think of is the following code (see some comments inside):

```
Sub qTest()

    Dim i
    For i = 1 To 1000 

        'this time we show user form twice
        If i > 100 And i < 103 Then
            UserForm1.Show vbModeless
        End If

        'to keep the loop waiting until you don't hide your UserForm
        'by pressing any button on UserForm

        Do While UserForm1.Visible
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Debug.Print i
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kazjaw, thanks for your answer. It doesn't seem to work however..
Here's a little example of what I want:

Public Sub test()

    For i = 1 To 300 Step 1
    
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = 88 Then
        
            UserForm2.Show 0
            
        End If
        
        DoEvents
        
    Next
    
End Sub


So basically for each time that I have an 88 in my column, I would like the Userform to open and ask if I want to delete it.
It works perfectly without the *vbModeless*, but if it is written like above it just executes the whole program and then opens userform

Comment: @user1297656, hope I get you right at the moment. See edition in my answer. If I'm still wrong please change your question to make it more clear and I'll delete my answer...

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! It works perfectly now! The only problem is that my program is too heavy and it slows it down... But thanks, this was really helpful! Cheers